# Cannot GET /foldername

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to access following url in my browser, but it throw error "can not get/foldername"

http://lineup.fezzee.com:8080/json/

Although when i access file in this folder, it works

I have given 777 folder permission

What i want is that when I hit http://lineup.fezzee.com:8080/json/ it will display all files in browser 
I am using Ubuntu server

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you any htaccess in this dir

Comment: It might be easier to write a php script that displays your files and gives them back to you (for examples as a json string).
Then you could get http://lineup.fezzee.com:8080/json/listfiles.php

Comment: what do you mean by "when i access file in this folder"? You access a file in your browser? in your ftp? or with a script? Also (wild guess here), perhaps your htaccess is blocking your folder/file structure from appearing in browser?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/enabling-apache-file-directory-indexing/  is this help you?

Comment: I can access file in browser

Comment: Rakes in my htaccess i wrote Options All +Indexes but it wont work